# Matching URLs against array of shortening services

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following list of URLs:

```
1 http://www.cnn.com/international/stories/423423532
2 http://www.traderscreener.com/blah
3 http://is.gd/fsdaGdfd3
4 http://goo.gl/23V534
5 http://bit.ly/54HFD
6 http://stackoverflow.com/question/ask
```

I would like to expand shortened URLs to their original form:

```
$headers = get_headers($URL, 1);
if (!empty($headers['Location'])) {
  $headers['Location'] = (array) $headers['Location'];
  $URL = array_pop($headers['Location']);
}
```

However, I need to match all URLs against an array of shortening services:

```
$array(
  'is.gd', 'bit.ly', 'goo.gl', 'wibi.us', 'tinyurl.com' // etc
)
```

In this case, this would have to filter out URLs 3, 4, and 5. I believe the most easy way of doing this would be to grab `***` in `http://***/blah`. Since I have little experience using regex, what would be the regex needed? Or is there a better way of approaching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do this is not to build a blacklist. Instead, query the URL and see if it redirects. Send a HEAD request, and look for the status code. If it's 3xx, then there's a redirect so you should look for the "Location" header and use that as the new URL.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, with my http wrapper: `$request = http_request("http://bit.ly/di5fZB");
if ($request->code == 301) {
  echo $request->headers['Location'];
}` One question though: is it enough to check for `substr($request->code, 0, 1) == 3` because all 3xx are redirects?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/^http:\/\/(is\.gd|bit\.ly|goog\.gl\|wibi\.us|tinyurl\.com)/i', $URL);
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to escpape the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the URL's will be in that format, you can use explode().

```
$url = "http://bit.ly/54HFD";
$tem = explode("/", $url);

$needles = array(
  'is.gd', 'bit.ly', 'goo.gl', 'wibi.us', 'tinyurl.com' // etc
)

foreach($needles as $needle) {
         $res = strpos($tem[2], $needle);
         if ($res !== false) DO_SOMEHING
}
```